# Importing a key to SmartCard HSM 4k

Tags: import, rsa, smartcard, hsm

I have an old private RSA key of length 4k that I want to import into a SmartCard-HSM 4k.
Is there an easy way doing that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 0):

If such function is supported, then it should be relatively easy.

However:

1. 4Kib RSA key components don't fit in a single APDU;
2. 4Kib is about the maximum that smart cards may support, and even then they may require specific configuration.

Problem 1 can be avoided using extended length APDU's, command chaining or using special "files" to write the key to.